# Reactjs mapping to objects in Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, arraylist

I've a JS file, which I'm trying to Map.
I would like to map to specific buttons, however I can not do that, could you please assist on it.
I've tried many options, but in my case, it is not working

---

```
{DlCards.map((dvlcards, cardtitle, link, srvbutton ) => {return(
    <Grid
        item
        xs = {dvlcards.grid_xs} 
        sm = {dvlcards.grid_sm} 
        md = {dvlcards.grid_md}
        container
        justify = 'space-between'
        style   = {{width: '25%', marginTop: 60}}>
        <Card
            variant   = "outlined"
            className = {classes.__ServCards__}>
            <CardContent>
                <Typography
                    gutterBottom
                    variant   = "h4"
                    color     = "textSecondary"
                    className = {classes.__cardtitles__}>
                    {cardtitle}
                </Typography>
            </CardContent>
            <CardActions>
                <Button
                    fullWidth 
                    size  = "small" 
                    component = {Link} to = {link}>
                    {srvbutton.name}
                </Button>
            </CardActions>
        </Card>
    </Grid>);
})}
```

Here is my JS file also

```
export let DlCards = [
     [{ 
         grid_xs:    3, 
         grid_sm:    3, 
         grid_md:    3, 
         link:       '/justalink',
         cardtitle:  'Some Text',
         srvbutton:  [{name: 'some name', mail: 'some email'}],
     }],
]
```

Answer (score 0):

you are dealing with a 2 dimensional array in your code and you might do something like:

```
DlCards.map(cardGroup => {
   
   cardGroups.map(({ dvlcards, cardtitle, link, srvbutton })=> (
      
      // ... your jsx here

   ))

})
```

as much as you are inside of rendering it, you should not go this way, because **it would create an O(n2) loop in your render function and its is totally not recommended**. my suggestion would be try to change the data structure you use to avoid creating and O(n2) loop inside of your render section of your code!

Comment: yes you can event do that, but make sure to use `useMemo` to memoise your calculations and prevent calculating it on every render

Comment: Somehow it is not returning the content

Comment: I've implemented your proposal but, the result is same - ```{DlCards.map(CardContent => {CardContent.map(({dvlcards, cardtitle, srvbutton}) = > (return(//JSX);))})}```

Comment: I think missing `return`. Try  `{DlCards.map(CardContent => CardContent.map(({dvlcards, cardtitle, srvbutton}) => <yourJSX /> ))}`